# PyGtk Program is not responding on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pygtk, py2exe

I just managed to get py2exe work on a Windows Virtual Machine but stumbled on another problem which I didn't have right after I installed GTK, Pango, Gobject etc. on that machine: When I launch a Python Script the window appears but it immediately stops responding. This happens too if I open a python interpreter and type:

```
import gtk
w = gtk.Window()
w.show()
```

I'm not allowed to post any images yet, but here's the link to a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJ0n.png

This is a problem for me, as if I create an executable with py2exe I get the same result when I execute the program.

Thank you for your help and for your time spent to help me! :)

**Solved! It seems installing ActivePython the installing GTK runtime, PyCairo, PyObject, PyGtk as administrator with compatibility mode for Windows Xp Service Pack 2 solved the problem. Thank you adw for your help and suggestions!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved! It seems installing ActivePython the installing GTK runtime, PyCairo, PyObject, PyGtk as administrator with compatibility mode for Windows Xp Service Pack 2 solved the problem. Thank you adw for your help and suggestions!**

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a main loop so GTK can process events, draw in the window, etc.

Add this to your program:

```
gtk.main()
```

See also: http://live.gnome.org/PyGTK/QuickStart

Comment: Don't worry I'm not a beginner, I've already added that to the end of the file. The problem doesn't come from there. What I showed above is in the python interpreter(you don't need to start a loop)

Comment: Does your normal development machine run Windows, Linux or something else; and does the program work properly there? Could you supply a minimal program that shows the problem?

Comment: I run Linux and Windows is being ran in a Virtual Machine. Even a simple program like:
import gtk;
w = gtk.Window();
w.show();
gtk.main();

gets this error. If the program is a PyGtk program it just stops responding right after it opened.

I supplied an example of a program that doesn't work on this link http://pastebin.com/An6z5Wti
Note: This isn't the only program that doesn't work, it's just an example. Any Gtk program stops responding(if I click it the End Now Dialog appears).

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: I know the path to the Glade file is "/home/calin/..." but this is changed in the other programs so that's not why it doesn't work. May it be because of the first line(#!/usr/bin/env python)?

Comment: You cannot use threads like that. First, try to avoid using threads at all. If you have some kind of long running function that you really cannot split up, you may put it in a thread, but you cannot directly access gtk objects from the secondary thread. Instead, to access gtk from another thread, use gobject.idle_add. See also: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq20.001.htp

Comment: if I don't use threads, my programs just go gray if they undergo some heavy processing. I don't know how to correctly use them but I will check that link out. The problem doesn't come from the threads, as any pygtk app freezes.