# PyGTK Window Crashes When Created

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, crash, pygtk

I am trying to create a simple PyGTK window running on Windows 7. I used the PyGTK-all-in-one installer from: [ftp.gnome.org](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.22/) to install the necessary PyGTK dependencies for 32-Bit Python 2.7.2. However, whenever I create a simple GTK window in IDLE using the code:

```
import gtk
mainWindow = gtk.Window()
mainWindow.show()
```

the window is displayed, but instantly stops responding and is unable to be moved, re-sized, etc. Is there a simple way to prevent this from happening?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running my code from the PyGtk Command Prompt rather than IDLE prevents the window from crashing.

**Edit:** Adding a main loop to my code, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009566/pygtk-program-is-not-responding-on-windows), prevents the window from crashing when run with IDLE.