# pygtk crash in windows XP

Tags: python, windows, crash, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to run this quite simple example with gtk in windows XP (32 bits):

```
import pygtk
import gtk

def create_window():
    window = gtk.Window()
    window.set_default_size(200, 200)
    window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)

    label = gtk.Label('Hello World')
    window.add(label)

    label.show()
    window.show()

create_window()
gtk.main()
```

The program shows the window, but just after that (I think that when it reaches "gtk.main()") it crashes showing the message "python.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close".
Somebody has a possible solution?

**SOLVED: You can have python (or the whole Anaconda package) installed, but you HAVE to eliminate whatever pycairo, gtk or pygtk module which is alredy in your computer. When you are sure of that, just run the file pygtk-all-in-one adequate for you (http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/), and, if you are lucky... It is done!!!**

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009566/pygtk-program-is-not-responding-on-windows

Comment: Maybe the problem is very similar to this one, but I'm not sure if it is exactly the same. Anyway, thank you for the reference.

Comment: I saw the update in your question. Have you really found the solution?

Comment: Yes, as far as I have checked, I think so. It seems that if you try to install pygtk-all-in-one without eliminate correctly the older packages (pycairo, gtk or pygtk), you can get problems. At least, this worked in my case.

Comment: So I shall put this as an answer and make it a wiki for future references.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP's update in the question:

> SOLVED: You can have python (or the whole Anaconda package) installed,
>   but you HAVE to eliminate whatever pycairo, gtk or pygtk module which
>   is alredy in your computer. When you are sure of that, just run the
>   file pygtk-all-in-one adequate for you
>   (http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/), and, if
>   you are lucky... It is done!!!